# Deploying war: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, liferay

I have an weird error when I'm trying to deploy my war file in liferay

```
РЅРѕСЏ 26, 2015 2:57:08 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\dev\liferay\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\site-hook
РЅРѕСЏ 26, 2015 2:57:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
```

That's all I have in my logs. I am using tomcat 7.042 with liferay 6.2
When I build my hook with maven it's ok excepting this line

```
[WARNING] Warning: selected war files include a WEB-INF/web.xml which will be ignored 
(webxml attribute is missing from war task, or ignoreWebxml attribute is specified as 'true')
```

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

and build section in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <pluginType>hook</pluginType>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The problem appeared ah hour ago, but recently everything was fine. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the 'maven-war-plugin' version 2.6 in your pom.xml